# jQuery th equals option on a table

Tags: jquery, html-table, equals

I have a table with header th names populated dynamically as id, title, description, externalid. I am trying to find column name with jQuery as `th:contans` to do operation on id. But interestingly it pulls externalid instead of id. I understood that contains picks column with id, but I am wondering if I could get some thing like equals instead of contains to avoid duplicate pulling values.

HTML Snippet

```
<table>
 <tr>
   <th><a>id</a></th>
   <th><a>Title</a></th>
   <th><a>description</a></th>
 </tr>
</table>



Jquery Snippet

 var table = $('#tblProjects');
    var findColumn = $(table.find('th:contains(' + columns + ')'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contains selector will look for partial matches also so if you are searching for `id` both `id` and `externalid` values will be matched.

You can write a custom filter to find the exact elements like

```
var findColumn = table.find('th').filter(function(){
    return $.trim($(this).text()) == columns
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $("#tblProjects tr th:contains('"+ columns +"')").each(function(){
         // do whatever you want with the selected th
 });
```